# One SQLiteConnection per thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite

I am using SQLite from system.data.sqlite.org

We need to access the database from many threads (for various reasons). I've read a lot about sqlite thread safe capabilities (the default synchronized access mode is fine for me).

I wonder if it is possible to simply open a connection per thread. Is something like this possible? I really don't care about race conditions (request something that hasn't been inserted yet). I am only interested in the fact that it is possible to access the data using one `SQLiteConnection` object per thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it's the proper way, as SQLite is not thread safe (by default. You can make it threadsafe compiling with some option). And just to ensure it works: SQLite is being used in some small websites, so multithreading is there :)

Here more information: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

Answer (score 5):

Given you use a separate connection per thread you should be fine.

From [docs](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.html)

> Note that SQLiteConnection instance is not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe. You should avoid using the **same** SQLiteConnection in several
>   threads at the same time. It is recommended to open a new connection
>   per thread and to close it when the work is done.